# How to transfer String from Servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

servlet file

```
String str = req.getParameter("str");
req.setAttribute("str", "java");
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/us.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

jsp file

```
<jsp:useBean id="str" class="hws" scope="request">
```

or

```
<div align="center">
    <textarea readonly name="" cols="50" rows="25"><%= request.getAttribute("str") %></ textarea>
</div>
<form action="/us" method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <textarea name="str" cols="50" rows="3">welcome to my program</textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use EL (Expression Language, those `${}` things). It has implicit access to request/session/application scoped attributes by just its attribute name.

```
<textarea readonly>${str}</textarea>
```

Be careful with [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) though whenever it concerns user-controlled input.

#### See also:

- [JSP tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Servlets tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 4):

While BalusC is correct, I wanted to point out the potential security risk with directly outputting a string. According to the [Java Servlet 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr152/index.html),

> In cases where escaping is desired
>   (for example, to help prevent
>   cross-site scripting attacks), the
>   JSTL core tag  can be used.

For example:

```
<c:out value=”${anELexpression}” />
```

This can help protected against [XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) attacks. See the [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/J2EE_Bad_Practices%3a_JSP_Expressions) page for more info.